# calculate binary expression - convert string to binary data

Tags: apache-flex, binary

I get a string like this: "000AND111"
I need to calculate this and return the result.
How I do it in Flex?

Answer (score 1):

just see this post thanks to the pingback by @powerlljf3

I would suggest a 3 phases approach.

1- write a small parser that split up the string in meaningful tokens (numbers and operands). Since Operands are all litterals and numbers are 0/1 combination, the parser is pretty easy (the grammer is LL1), so regular expressions can be really do the work here.

2- after building up the sequency of tokens and what is tecnically call the parsed expression tree (the sequency of tokens and operands), just implements any operand with the specific function (the link to my blog, works for few of the common boolean algebra operands)

3- finally just start reading tokens from left to right, and apply function where operands are found.

Answer (score 0):

I would look through this http://www.nicolabortignon.com/as3-bitwise-operations/.  It has many examples of binary math that can be used in AS3.